# Seamless Image alignment, no matter what orientation with CSS?

Tags: css, alignment, css-float

my brother wants his archive like Terry Richards (or simply tumblrs) archive http://www.terrysdiary.com/archive on his site: http://www.davidgoltz.de/2011/blog-page/

I tried to do a little stuff with floats and stuff but it doesnt work. Is this hard work? :-)

Answer (score 1):

Only thing i remember that does this sort of thing is jQuery Masonry plugin.

I have never had a need to use it ( or this style )

I also believe i have seen quite a few different methods to do this though...

http://masonry.desandro.com/index.html